# Having issues getting my code running in VBA. "Else without If" Issue

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me out, every time I try to run this code it gives me the error in title. I'm trying to get it to if I type in Amnesty it'll filter certain columns while if I type in Audits it'll filter it separately. I do plan on adding a few other options as well.

```
Sub Filter()

If Sheets("Data").Range("L7") = 1003030 Then GoTo ICQA


ICQA:

If Sheets("Data").Range("K7") = "Amnesty" Then


With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Amnesty"
.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="ItemAmnestied"
.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="EACH"
.AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="Total"

.AutoFilter Field:=6, _
             Criteria1:=Array("Friday,Malachi Justice", "Townsend,Bryan Desmond", "OReilly,Phil", "Singh,Vick", "Qureshi,Afsah A", "Mutapcic,Ajla", "Grewal,Talvinder", "Guardado,Kevin"), _
                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
                   
ElseIf Sheets("Data").Range("K7") = "Audits" Then


With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Audits"
                   
End If
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `End If` somewhere. This type of error can be stopped by always ensuring that code within `If\Else\End If` is always indented. Also, using `GoTo` is not recommended.

Comment: Actually I think you are missing `End With`s.

Comment: The error usually appear at the ElseIf line

Comment: You are missing several `End With`'s.  This gives the same error message for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As several comments have been written to specify, you're missing some `End`-statements in your code. A good practice to avoid these errors, is to always work with indents. I've gone through your code and made some changes.

You should get used to indents right away; it will save you hours of debugging obvious flaws.

As comments mention above, you should avoid GoTo's. I've removed it from your code.

```
Sub Filter()

    If Sheets("Data").Range("L7") = 1003030 Then
        If Sheets("Data").Range("K7") = "Amnesty" Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Amnesty"
                .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="ItemAmnestied"
                .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="EACH"
                .AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:="Total"
                .AutoFilter Field:=6, _
                             Criteria1:=Array("Friday,Malachi Justice", "Townsend,Bryan Desmond", "OReilly,Phil", "Singh,Vick", "Qureshi,Afsah A", "Mutapcic,Ajla", "Grewal,Talvinder", "Guardado,Kevin"), _
                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
        ElseIf Sheets("Data").Range("K7") = "Audits" Then
            With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Audits"
            End With
                
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```